# Ionic 3 Cordova - Apple sign in sometimes throws ASAuthorizationErrorUnknown on first login attempt leading to apps getting rejected

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, apple-sign-in

I have a Ionic 3 white label application and i am using this plugin:

https://github.com/zmagyar/cordova-plugin-applesignin

Everything seems to be working fine and there don't seem to be any issues while testing the application as i never experienced the error but when submitted to the AppStore, the reviewer sometimes blocks the application as having a bug related to Apple Sign in.

I added a logging system to the app that helped me identify the error thrown by Apple sign in plugin on occasion is: ASAuthorizationErrorUnknown.

Not all apps get rejected, even though they have the same code.
A app in particular has been repeatedly rejected. The apps don't have any differences in how the login is handled.

I tested the App on both an emulator and a physical phone with the exact same iOS version the reviewer tested on.

My questions are:

Could it be the plugin? (I previously tried other plugins that didn't work). Considering the answer is coming straight from Apple, and it works in 99.9% of the time its probably not the plugin, right?

Do you know what could cause that error?

Do you know of an alternative of implementing apple login on a Ionic 3 app that worked for you?

Fingers crossed :)

Thanks